# Sequence empty right after setting

Tags: expl3

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\ProvideDocumentCommand \Union { O{\cup} O{,} m }
{
  \typeout{#3}
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_lmpa_seq { #2 } { #3 }
  \seq_show:N \l_tmpa_seq
  \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { #1 }
}

\begin{document}
$\Union{a,b,c}$
\end{document}
```

gives in the console

```
a,b,c
The sequence \l_tmpa_seq is empty
> .
<recently read> }

l.13 $\Union{a,b,c}
                   $
```

with no (visible) printed output.  I can't for the life of me figure out what is going awry.  I've also tried the analogous `clist` implementation to no avail…

Comment: you've set `\l_lmpa_seq` and then are trying to use `\l_tmpa_seq`.  Note the `l` versus `t`.

Comment: @A.Ellett I legitimately been struggling to understand this for nearly a week… and it's a typo! Thanks for catching it, at the *very* least!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is caused by a typo.